# Linux: Replace value for tab separated line in text file using sed

Tags: linux, bash, sed

Linux: How to replace value for tab separated line in text file using sed.

Sample data in myfile:

```
98104930    CLOSED  /data/nightlybackup/adx.ngx kyangx@nginx.com
```

Expected:

```
98104930    FIXED   /data/nightlybackup/adx.ngx kyangx@nginx.com

id=98104930
qa=kyangx@nginx.com
testcase=/data/nightlybackup/adx.ngx
oldstatus=CLOSED
newstatus=FIXED
```

I tried:

```
sed -i "s/${id}\\t${oldstatus}\\t${testcase}\\t${qa}/${id}\\t${newstatus}\\t${testcase}\\t${qa}/g" ${myfile}
```

but that doesn't work. Can someone please provide the solution for same?

Comment: please provide the full script, including the values for variables like `id`, `oldstatus`.

Comment: @krzyk The values are on the 5 lines before `I tried`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to double escape the tabs, just use `\t`.
And you have to use different separator in sed, because one of your variables uses `/` (`testcase`) so sed is fooled by it, e.g. you can use `#`.

```
sed -i "s#${id}\t${oldstatus}\t${testcase}\t${qa}#${id}\t${newstatus}\t${testcase}\t${qa}#g" ${myfile}
```

In sed you can use almost any character as a separator, `s///`, `s###`, `s,,,` etc.

Comment: Works fine krzyk! You are awesome!

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using awk for this:

```
$ awk -v id='98104930' \
      -v newstatus='FIXED' \
      -v testcase='/data/nightlybackup/adx.ngx' \
      -v qa='kyangx@nginx.com' \
      -v OFS='\t' \
     '$1 == id && $3 == testcase && $4 == qa {$2=newstatus} 1' file
98104930    FIXED   /data/nightlybackup/adx.ngx kyangx@nginx.com
```

This way you avoid the trouble with special characters, eg `.` matches everyting, and `/data/nightly...` will break your substitution when `/` is used as delimiter.

Comment: Thanks for your help, i used below sed method and it worked.